# How do I install a PostgreSQL extension in Windows?

Tags: postgresql, windows, installation, postgresql-extensions

In Linux (with Ubuntu or Debian) if I want to install `gen_salt()`, I first install the -contrib package.

```
sudo apt install postgresql-contrib
```

Then I install the extension in the database,

```
psql -d myDatabase -c "create extension pgcrypto"
```

How do I get `gen_salt()` and `crypt()` working in Windows?

Comment: The pg_crypto and gen_salt functionality is not working in Postgres Windows. It has to be enabled so as to store a encypted password. Any idea, how it is possible?

Comment: So what's the error message you get? And what is the exact command you used to create the extension? And what is your exact Postgres version? [edit] your question by clicking on the [edit] link below it. Do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: If you're having a problem with pgcrypto specifically, please ask another question related to just that. Posting the exact problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent:

Login in postgresql, connect on the database you are having problem then issue:

```
create extension pgcrypto;
```

Is that.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, the installer used wasn't provided by PostgreSQL, but instead by one of their [third party providers](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/). Usually these third parties bundle by default the `-contrib` modules that would be packaged and installed independently on Linux distros. This is in part because Windows lacks a system to tie into and provide additional abilities like `apt` or `dnf`.

Because the installer provided the extension, all you have to do is run `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;` to tie it into the database.

```
psql -d myDatabase -c "CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;"
```

Or connect to the database and run

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
```

Comment: CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto; ---------------------------------------------

thanks, it worked for me .

Comment: Can I ask for example how to install pglogical on Windows? i'm searching for solution for 2 days I didn't find where to start exactly.